# Trying to connect java swing to a mysql database on a local network server

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, intellij-idea, datagrid

I am trying to connect to my database from a IntelliJ environment, using java spring. I tried it too in DataGrip with the same result.

Using "data sources and drivers", i try to set up my connection. Typing in my host ip and port.
Authentication: my user and password who has permissions in my database.
Define my database.

When I test the connection it gives me the following error:
[28000][1045] Access denied for user 'ERP_admin'@'DESKTOP-FK4UCCU.***.***.***' (using password: YES)
(the *** being workrelated scopes)

I did make the connection in Visual Studio Code with a connector.But apparently jetBrains is a little harder.

My wildcard in MYSQL is %. Or should i add something here?

I have been searching for a couple of days so any help is welcome.

I tried making connection to it via the root. Didn't work.
Tried other databases. Didn't work.
Edited my user to all privileges. Didn't work.

Comment: This is usually due to user misconfiguration in MySQL. You should have some log in the DB server that might help debugging this.

Comment: You need to `grant` connect for the user and *from* the client host or specify the host as part of the `create user` command

Answer (score 0):

Computer magic.
A new day, a new start.

Waking up my computer this morning and fired up my database.
Was checking my logging only to see i didnt have any. So i: SET global general_log = 1;

To get some data i wanted to try my connection again. It had some other test properties set. So i re-entered my user and password and pressed test connection.

Expecting another error i allready switched screen. Immediatly second guessing what i saw, i checked intellij again. And yeah magic. Connection succeeded.

Turning on logging fixed it?

Anyway thanks for the comments.